# PHP Display all images from DB in a img tagg - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo, blob

Im trying to display alla images in a `<img>` from the db but i am only getting a broken image!
I am storing the ['tmp_name'] as  LONGBLOB and the ['name'] as type in my tabel.

```
  $query = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM images");
                $query->execute();


                    $row = $query->fetchAll();

                    foreach($row as $img){
                        echo "<pre>";var_dump($img['name']);"</pre>";

                        echo "<img src=".$img["name"].">";
                    }

                    //header("Content-type: ".$row['type']);
                    print $row['name'];
                    die();
```

Should i use ['tmp_name'] or ['name'] in the `<img>`?

Comment: You have store a file on your server in the first place. Storing only a temporary name wont make  a file itself stored

Comment: Please read a PHP tutorial about file uploads.

Comment: `var_dump($img['name'])` is the name of the file 
What do you meen i have to store a file on my server?

Comment: You are so confused with everything as I see, try to get tutorials on file upload. Not clear what you want. you want to store your images in database blobs, or store it on server and store the path of it in db, etc...

Comment: `['tmp_name']`? Are you stuffing $_FILES into the db? That's just information ABOUT the upload, not the actual upload, and none of the information in $_FILES would let you directly access the uploaded image via an `<img>` tag. you need to move the upload into your document root somewhere, store that path, and then THAT path is what you put into `<img src=...>`

Comment: So `var_dump($img)` gives something like `array ( 'name' => 'foobar.jpg', 'tmp_name' => '/tmp/iujaiweugaeg' )`? If so, then you have not actually stored the file anywhere. If it's something different, tell us what it is.

Comment: ohh i seee! deceze  &  lolka_bolka! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img src="">` should include the full server path where your image is successfully uploaded. Also should include the image extension as well (.jpg, .png, .gif). should look like similar to following.

`<img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/160xn/p0306tt8.png">`

Easiest way is to check the source code of page and see if you get complete / correct path to the image. If not, check/change your code for missing part.